# Issue with PHP and SQL query converting to Int

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

i have put a query together that gathers data from a couple different tables and this works fine in SQL server studio but when i try and run the query in PHP using an  ODBC connection i get the following error

```
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Default' to data type int., SQL state 22005 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\T_A\People.php on line 40
Error in SQL
```

Below is the query

```
SELECT     ATDSchedulingRule.Name, ATDSchedulingRule.Remark, ATDShiftDetail.WorkHour,     RIGHT(ATDShiftDetail.StartTime, 6) AS StartTime, 
                  RIGHT(ATDShiftDetail.EndTime, 6) AS EndTime, RIGHT(CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.ID, 4) AS ClockNo,     CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode
FROM         ATDShiftDetail INNER JOIN
                  ATDSchedulingRule ON ATDShiftDetail.ATDShift_Ref = ATDSchedulingRule.Shift_Ref2 INNER JOIN
                  CHINA_VISION_PubCards INNER JOIN
                  CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel ON CHINA_VISION_PubCards.PubPersonnel_Ref = CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Reference ON 
                  ATDSchedulingRule.Name = RIGHT(CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.ID, 4)
WHERE     (ATDShiftDetail.WorkHour > 0) AND (CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Telephone > '1') AND (ATDSchedulingRule.Name = '1877')
```

And here is the PHP

```
 Public function GetPersonData() {
   $conn = odbc_connect('easydo', '', '');
    if (!$conn) {
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT     ATDSchedulingRule.Name, ATDSchedulingRule.Remark, ATDShiftDetail.WorkHour,   RIGHT(ATDShiftDetail.StartTime, 6) AS StartTime, 
                  RIGHT(ATDShiftDetail.EndTime, 6) AS EndTime, RIGHT(CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.ID, 4) AS ClockNo, CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode
FROM         ATDShiftDetail INNER JOIN
                  ATDSchedulingRule ON ATDShiftDetail.ATDShift_Ref = ATDSchedulingRule.Shift_Ref2 INNER JOIN
                  CHINA_VISION_PubCards INNER JOIN
                  CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel ON CHINA_VISION_PubCards.PubPersonnel_Ref =     CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Reference ON 
                  ATDSchedulingRule.Name = RIGHT(CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.ID, 4)
WHERE     (ATDShiftDetail.WorkHour > 0) AND (CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Telephone > '1') AND (ATDSchedulingRule.Name = $this->Op )
";

    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    if (!$rs) {
        exit("Error in SQL");
    }
    var_dump($rs);
}
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: I would recommend getting this pass through sql out of your application. You should move this to a stored procedure or at the very least you should parameterize this. My guess is that you need to single quotes in your where predicate that is looking at ATDSchedulingRule.Name

Comment: Aside from the above comment, when running it in SQL Server studio are you sure it's fetching the entire result set? The error is from a varchar column being converted implicitly to int, likely one of the WHERE clause conditions. It's hard to say without seeing the schema/data, but I'd guess ATDScheduleRule.Name has a value of "default" in a row which then fails conversion.